# Kendo DropDown returning Value instead of Text

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, dropdown

I use the dropdown list as an EditorTemplate for a column in the grid:

```
@model Guid?

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
    .DataValueField("Id")
    .DataTextField("Name")
    .DataSource(dataSource =>
    {
        dataSource.Read(read => read.Action(MVC.Controller.ActionNames.ActionName_Read, MVC.Controller.Name))
        .ServerFiltering(true);
    })
    .ValuePrimitive(true)
)
```

My Controller:

```
public virtual ActionResult ActionName_Read()
        {
            var applicationID = AppSettings.Id.Guid;

            var return = _db.table.Where(w => w.ID == appID).Select(s => new { s.Name, Id = s.Guid});

            return Json(return, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

My Column:

```
columns.Bound(c => c.Name).Filterable(f => f.UI("$.proxy(filterFunction, {field: Name})").Operators(o => o.ForString(e => e.Clear().IsEqualTo("Is equal to").IsNotEqualTo("Is not equal to")))).EditorTemplateName("EditorTemplateName");
```

I added .ValuePrimitive(true) and that returns the ID, but if I remove that, it returns [object object].

I have the Name and the ID return from the action, but only the name field gets populated, and it gets populated by the ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looped into the change event of my DropDownList in the EditorTemplate and did the following:

```
function selectRow(name, event) {
var rowUid = $("#Name").closest("tr").attr("data-uid");
var rowItem = $("#" + name).data("kendoGrid").dataSource.getByUid(rowUid);

var currentName = event.sender._focused[0].textContent;
var currentDataSource = event.sender.dataSource._data;

for (var i = 0; i < currentDataSource.length; i++) {
    if (currentDataSource[i].Name=== currentName) {
        rowItem.set("Id", currentDataSource[i].Id);
        rowItem.set("Name", currentDataSource[i].Name);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .ValueTemplate() property.

here is one example https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/dropdownlist/template

```
.ValueTemplate("#:yourObject.Name#")
```

Comment: I added .ValueTemplate("#:data.Name#") but it still returns the ID

Comment: Did you try to log your data values? Check if the names you are looking for are there

Comment: I can see from the return action that the values are there, I can see the names when selecting the item, but then all I see is the ID in the column field.

Comment: I also tried to get the text value in JavaScript and I could only find it using: e.sender._focused[0].textContent